# How to use variable once for several times in db expression?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I use below code for select data.The '$var' variable has identical value.How can I use '$var' once for thrice?

```
$where->expression("subject like ? or contract_number like ? or description like ?",
                     array("%$var%","%$var%","%$var%"));
```

Comment: What you show is how I would do it; Just use the variable three times in the bindvalues array

Comment: instead use ':var' in place of '?' and then bind value for :var

Comment: Not work in zend-framework2.error:The number of replacements in the expression does not match the number of parameters

Answer (score 3):

You can use Named Parameters:

```
$where->expression("subject like :bob or contract_number like :bob or description like :bob",
    array(":bob" => "%$var%")
);
```